# String of certain length in Sailsjs Model

Tags: sails.js, waterline

How can I enforce a Model property to be exactly 32 characters long?

I have tried

```
key : {
    type: 'string',
    len : 32
}
```

but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, let me tell you what i did.

After reading hours y figure out that "columnType" property is the solution. It works together with "type" property. For example. I have a "description" field. It looks like:

> descripcion: {
>         type: 'string',
>         columnType: 'varchar (27)' }

And it works. (this is for mysql db).

I hope this works for you. This is on the docs.
[Model verbatim field](https://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/models-and-orm/attributes)

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the correct way to do it is:

```
        maxLength   : 32,
        minLength   : 32,
```