# sails.js waterline: maxLength not set in DB

Tags: node.js, sails.js, waterline

I have set the validation rule maxLength for one of my fields in one of my models and it is recognized by sails.js if my input is too long. My problem is that if I check my database it shows a field length of 255 for my mysql db. I would expect it to be the same as my maxLength value.

I've found this on StackOverflow:
[SailsJS - How to specify string attribute length without getting error when creating record?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21359455/sailsjs-how-to-specify-string-attribute-length-without-getting-error-when-crea)

Since this has been opened Sails.js made a lot of progress and so I don't know if custom validation rules is still the way to go. I don't like this because it looks more like a temporary hack rather than a real solution.

Is this expected behavior or a bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know you do not need the answer anymore, but maybe other people do.

You must use the size attribute for this purpose.

On the doc's says:

> If supported in the adapter, can be used to define the size of the attribute. For example in MySQL, size can be specified as a number (n) to create a column with the SQL data type: varchar(n).

Just use it like this

```
attributes: {
  name: {
    type: 'string',
    size: 24
  }
}
```

https://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/models-and-orm/attributes#size