# Waterline error: "Unknown rule: default"

Tags: javascript, sails.js, waterline

I'm getting the following error when calling `.create()` on a model.

Model:

```
attributes: {
    user : {
      type: 'integer'
    },
    number : {
      type: 'string'
    }
  }
```

Call:

```
sails.models.phone.create({ 
  user: 2,
  number: '5555555555',
  updated_at: Sun Nov 27 2016 16:59:45 GMT-0800 (PST) 
});
```

Error:

```
Unknown rule: default
    at Object.matchRule (/Developer/repos/bond/api/node_modules/waterline/node_modules/anchor/lib/match/matchRule.js:38:11)
    at Anchor.to (/Developer/repos/bond/api/node_modules/waterline/node_modules/anchor/index.js:106:48)
    at afterwards (/Developer/repos/bond/api/node_modules/waterline/lib/waterline/core/validations.js:229:41)
    at /Developer/repos/bond/api/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:52:16
    at Object.async.forEachOf.async.eachOf (/Developer/repos/bond/api/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:236:30)
    at Object.async.forEach.async.each (/Developer/repos/bond/api/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:209:22)
    at _eachValidation (/Developer/repos/bond/api/node_modules/waterline/lib/waterline/core/validations.js:189:11)
    at /Developer/repos/bond/api/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:181:20
    at Object.async.forEachOf.async.eachOf (/Developer/repos/bond/api/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:233:13)
    at Object.async.forEach.async.each (/Developer/repos/bond/api/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:209:22)
    at Validator.validate (/Developer/repos/bond/api/node_modules/waterline/lib/waterline/core/validations.js:144:9)
    at /Developer/repos/bond/api/node_modules/waterline/lib/waterline/query/validate.js:42:25
    at /Developer/repos/bond/api/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:718:13
    at Immediate.iterate [as _onImmediate] (/Developer/repos/bond/api/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:262:13)
    at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:383:17)
```

**How do I fix this?**

I've looked into [similar errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21359455/sailsjs-how-to-specify-string-attribute-length-without-getting-error-when-crea), but none of my models have a `default` attribute, including the `phone` model shown above. Why is this happening, and how do I solve it?

---

**Solution**

So it turns out that a Waterline call of `.update()` changes the input information. I had written a function to create or update waterline models, and when they fixed the [auto updated_at issue](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/issues/3821), they must've altered the incoming info.

My previous code that did not work:

```
createOrUpdate: function(model, primary, data){
  return model.update(primary, data)
  .then(function updateCB(updated){
    if (updated.length == 0){
      return model.create(data) //data here had an added updated_at field
      .then(function(created){
        return created;
      });
    }

    if (updated.length > 0){
      updated = updated[0];
    }
    return updated;
  });
}
```

My new code that does work:

```
createOrUpdate: function(model, primary, data){
  const data1 = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data)); // deep copy
  const data2 = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data)); // deep copy
  return model.update(primary, data1)
  .then(function updateCB(updated){
    if (updated.length == 0){
      return model.create(data2)
      .then(function(created){
        return created;
      });
    }

    if (updated.length > 0){
      updated = updated[0];
    }
    return updated;
  });
}
```

Comment: The column name after creation is `updatedAt`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't call update with:

```
updated_at: Sun Nov 27 2016 16:59:45 GMT-0800 (PST)
```

Updated_at is automatically filled field. Remove it from request (call as you call it) and it will work.

Comment: Thanks for catching that! I actually didn't manually call with that field, so I didn't notice it. Got it fixed now!

Comment: See my added solution for why I was so confused since this had been working for months. I'll bring this up with the Waterline team.